# Using multiple servers to send mails for single domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

I'd like to use multiple servers for sending mails like so:

server A: news@domain.com
server B: all other addresses for domain.com.

The most important thing is the ability to send mails from server A.

I'm wondering if this is possible and if it is, how would I go about configuring this in terms of dns/spf records etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v=spf1 a mx a:mx1.domain1.com a:mx1.domain2.com a:mx1.domain3.com ~all
```

Assuming you have mx1.domain1.com pointing to server one etc.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSPF.org has a nice [SPF record generator](http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html).